# Docker postgres change username and password

Tags: postgresql, docker

I am using the [`mdillon/postgis`](https://hub.docker.com/r/mdillon/postgis/) image as my containerized database. I have created a database that is owned by a user I created using the image's username and password environment variables. Now I need to changes that user's username and password.

I successfully changed the password but I could not change the username because you can change the current user's username.

I tired logging in as the `postgres` user but I get an error saying theres is no such user.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connect to the database as the firstly created user (lets call that user `old_user`) and create a new superuser

```
CREATE USER mysuperuser WITH SUPERUSER CREATEDB CREATEROLE LOGIN PASSWORD 'mysuperuser'
```

Now disconnect and connect again as that suepruser.
Then change `old_user` user's username:

```
ALTER USER old_user RENAME TO "new-user";
```

Then change `new-user` user's password:

```
ALTER USER "new-user" WITH PASSWORD 'new_password';
```

Finally reconnect as the `new-user` and delete the `superuser`

```
DROP USER mysuperuser;
```

You can see all users with:

```
SELECT usename
FROM pg_catalog.pg_user;
```